# Return JSON data from a Mongoose document to client Javascript

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose

I'm trying to return the JSON data in a mongoose document, and then display it using Angular. There's no errors on the page when using this code. The $http.get method in the Angular IndexCtrl never makes it to success, which leads me to believe the problem is how I'm implementing the API get method.  Any help rewriting that method to return properly greatly appreciated!

To clarify: what I want is to be able to access the document like a JSON Object so I can display the data to the client.

**update: it does produce the error:**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/tracks
```

**It takes a while for that error to show in the console**

**the api method**

```
app.get("/api/tracks", function(req, res) {
return Track.find({}, function (err, tracks) {
  if (err) {
    res.send(500);
    return;
  }
   return res.json({
  tracks: tracks
    });
  });
});
```

**the mongoose database**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var uristring = 
  process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 
  'mongodb://localhost/HelloMongoose';

var mongoOptions = { db: { safe: true }};

var db = mongoose.createConnection(uristring, mongoOptions, function (err, res) {
      if (err) { 
        console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
      } else {
        console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
      }
  });

//a Schema for a track
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  location: String,
  description: String
});

var Track = mongoose.model('Track', Schema);

var spot = new Track({name: 'zildjian'});
spot.save(function (err) {
  console.log('saved');
  if (err) // ...
  console.log('meow');
});
```

**The Angular controller**

```
function IndexCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/api/tracks').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.tracks = data.tracks;
      console.log($scope.tracks + "scope tracks data");  //This does not log! it never makes it this far
    });

}
```

**The Jade template that displays $scope.tracks**

```
p There are {{tracks.length}} posts

div(ng-repeat='track in tracks')
  h3 {{track.name}}
  div {{track.description}}
```

Comment: Add an error clause to your $http.get. I suspect there is an error there: error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
    })

Answer (score 3):

I was not pulling the entries from the model correctly.  Here is how I fixed it:

```
app.get("/api/tracks", function (req, res) {
var track = [];

var Track = mongoose.model('Track', trackSchema);
  Track.find({}, function (err, records) {
    records.forEach(function (post, i) {
      track.push({
        id: i,
        title: post.title,
        text: post.text.substr(0, 50) + '...'
      });
    });
    res.json({
      track: track
    });
  });
};
}
```

Comment: Can it be that this is the only way to get j